# Exact word match using index or find method - python

Tags: python, indexing, find

I have a string "the then there" and I want to search for exact/complete word, for e.g. in this case "the" appears only once. But using index() or find() methods thinks the appears three times as it is partial matching with "then" and "there" too.  I like to use either of these methods, any way I can tweak them to work?

```
>>> s = "the then there"
>>> s.index("the")
0
>>> s.index("the",1)
4
>>> s.index("the",5)
9
>>> s.find("the")
0
>>> s.find("the",1)
4
>>> s.find("the",5)
9
```

Comment: use regex `\bthe\b`

Answer (score 2):

To find the first position of the *exact/complete word* within a large text, try to apply the following approach using `re.search()` and `match.start()` functions:

```
import re

test_str = "when we came here, what we saw that the then there the"
search_str = 'the'
m = re.search(r'\b'+ re.escape(search_str) +r'\b', test_str, re.IGNORECASE)
if m:
    pos = m.start()
    print(pos)
```

The output:

```
36
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start

Answer (score 1):

Firstly convert the string to list of words using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and then search for the word.

```
>>> s = "the then there"
>>> s_list = s.split() # list of words having content: ['the', 'then', 'there']
>>> s_list.index("the")
0
>>> s_list.index("then")
1
>>> s_list.index("there")
2
```

Comment: Performance is an issue for my use case as it could be a very big file and therefore trying to avoid making a huge list...

Comment: Anyway it is a huge file. Either you need to store it as `str` or `list` but you need to store it somewhere. Right? Read the content as string, form a list. If you are even more interested in saving the space. After you get the list, convert it to dictionary with word as key and value as the index of first occurence of that word. Explicitly delete the variable not in use like the one storing string and list